# Configuring thouands of related products in Magento?

Tags: magento, custom-software

I'm at a stage with a Magento store I'm developing where I've added all the products (all 6000 of them) and now would like to configure related products to up my conversion rate a bit. I was wondering if there was an extension anybody knew of that functions similarly to [this one](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/automatic-related-products.html), with the most current version of Magento (Community Edition, 1.6.1).

If not, would anyone be able to provide some pointers for writing a script that will run through each product and add 1-5 related products. I have a fairly basic idea of taking product title text and just doing a simple text similarity query between other product titles for now, just to get some related products up there, but the Magento database isn't making a terribly large amount of sense.

Thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this. :)

Answer (score 3):

I hadn't noticed they'd released a newer version of the extension I linked, for anyone in the same dilemna.